# Seek and reverse seek in a VLCJ application

Tags: java, vlcj, vlcj-javafx

I am "seeking" the ability to seek forward and backwards on a video being played under vlcj. Information found in the documentation for vlcj API apparently refers to methods that no longer exist.

Is there still a way to do a forward and reverse seek on a video being played by vlcj? If so, how is this done?

Edit to answer questions asked by Slaw below:

1. I am using VLCJ 4.7.3, with vlcj-javafx V1.1.0.
2. On the site:
   https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayer/seek

there are several references to a seek() function provided by the MediaPlayer class. That function does not exist in the current vlcj.

3. On a tutorial provided by TutorialsPoint at:

   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vlcj/vlcj_seek.htm

there is a reference to a function called

```
mediaPlayer().controls().skipWhile();
```

which not only does not exist in the current vlcj that I am using, but is not actually used in the seek example program provided below the referance!

Comment: Which version of VLCJ are you using? What is the method that seems to "no longer exist"?

Comment: Slaw: please see the added information provided in my question above.

Comment: I assume you're talking about this [`MediaPlayer`](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/4.7.0/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/base/MediaPlayer.html) class? There indeed does not seem to be a `seek` method, but it does have a `controls()` method which returns a `ControlsApi`, and that class has a `setTime` method and a `skipTime` method. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The way to seek with contemporary versions of vlcj is to use `skipTime` or `skipPosition` with a positive or negative delta:

```java
mediaPlayer.controls().skipTime(deltaMillis);
```

Or:

```java
mediaPlayer.controls().skipPosition(deltaPosition);
```

If you want to seek to absolute times/positions:

```java
mediaPlayer.controls().setTime(timeMillis);
```

Or (position between 0.0 and 1.0):

```java
mediaPlayer.controls().setPosition(position);
```

Note that tabnine and tutorialspoint are not the official or sanctioned documentation for vlcj, so if that's out of date that's an issue for them and not a problem with vlcj's documentation.

In fact, `skipWhile` has *never* been a vlcj API function.

Instead, you should look here, or the GitHub project directly:

https://javadoc.io/doc/uk.co.caprica/vlcj/latest/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/base/MediaPlayer.html
https://javadoc.io/doc/uk.co.caprica/vlcj/latest/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/base/ControlsApi.html

Comment: Then this leads to another question. I had used skipPosition() and skipTime() to move forward and backward in a video prior to making this post. Unfortunately, they only perform one "skip" to a specific point in the video. This is inadequate if I want to implement a rewind or fast forward function. My question is: how do I implement such a function? I will, however, ask this question in another post.